# Postures of body while worship the god or during prayer?

Tags: prayer

What is right way to hold the hand while doing the prayer? I found some images from http://www.spiritualresearchfoundation.org/spiritual-practice/prayer/how-to-pray/

[image]

[image]

But this blog is too long. Can someone provide short answer?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in either of the 2 pics.When we do namaskaram we usually hold the hands in anjali mudra(the one which is shown in pics).Holding hands near your chest is more usual than near ur head,but thts  generally done while finishing off the namaskaraThere are of course many other mudras used in ritualistic worship.But mostly those are for advanced users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if Puranas and Vedas provide the Scientific explanation/speculation for various position of hands and fingers while worshiping the God. Very less information is present about Chakras in Puranas.

[Agni Purana Part 1 Chapter 26](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12915/3/Chapter1_1-80p.pdf) (Pg No- 66 and 67) provides various positions but doesn't provide any Scientific explanation.

> 1. (I now) describe the characteristic of (the different) positions of fingers (mudrä) (which) bring (the worshipper)  nearer (to the object of worship). Anjali (folding of hands)  is the first
>      mudrä. (The second) is the Vandani (fingers interlocked) to be placed
>      near the heart.
> 2. With the left fist folded and the thumb erect, the right thumb interwoven with the erect left thumb is said to be (the third one).
> 3. (These are) the three common formations. The (following are) not common. By the unyoking of the smallest and other fingers eight
>      positions (are formed) in order.
> 4. The first eight basic syllables are repeated in order. One has to bend the three fingers commencing with the little finger, with the
>      thumb.
> 5. One has to raise up the to the face the ninth mystic syllable. Then the left hand is raised up and bent half slowly.
> 6. These are the mudras of the limbs of Varäha in order. Then the left fist having been kept closed, the fingers are released one by one.
> 7. The same position is held by the right hand also and the previous position is bent down. The left fist (is held) with the thumb erect.
>      This results in the accomplishment of the mudra.

Neither those nuance and subtle things (of given website) have proper scriptural evidence nor they were recounted by a sage in Advanced Tapasya. So, these instructions of Agni Purana can be followed without considering them.